# Why to substitute EventArgs by generic parameter if the event does not generate data?

Tags: c#, events, generics, delegates, event-handling

I am having difficulties to understand the following phrase from from MSDN [EventHandler Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

- *"If your event does not generate event data, substitute [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for the generic type parameter; ..."*

Do I understood correctly that that the data generated by an event is stored in an instance of `EventArgs`?

Collateral curiosity:
Does this phrase mean that if the event generate data then don't use generic type EventArgs? Why?

The main question is:
Why to bother about `EventArgs` (to make it generic or leave it non-generic), if the event does not generate data?

**Update:**
From the mentioned article and the enclosed in it code example I understood that instead of delegate:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I am to use

```
public delegate void EventHandler<EventArgs>(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

when my event does not generate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no advantage to the second over the first if you are just using `EventArgs`.  The documentation likely just didn't mention this second possiblity as it was easier just to show the single delegate definition with the generic parameter in all of the examples.

Also, it is common to pass `EventArgs.Empty` rather than `null`.

If you event does have data, you need to subclass `EventArgs` and then use that subclass (in the example they use `MyEventArgs`).  `EventArgs` itself has no properties to hold data.

Comment: This does not answer the question why use generic (sublassed) EventArgs when having no data with event.+1 for your comment to the answer to my question [Would it be simple to change this code for thread synchronized queueing?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15054314/2031316) which deserved an answer upvote but could not be done for comment

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even realize you had asked both questions.  As far as your question here, there is no advantage to using a subclass of `EventArgs` (and a generic `EventHandler`) when there is no data to pass.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, the generic type parameter in constrained by `EventArgs` (`where TEventArgs : EventArgs`).  This means this is the most basic type the the `EventHandler` delgate supports.

When calling your event handler, can you just send `null` instead of an `EventArgs` instance?

As for why, I'm not sure why they require all events to have arguments, probably seemed like a good idea at the time.

One reason why they require `EventArgs` is because (before generics) the [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) delegate required `EventArgs`, so it might be to preserve compatibility.

Comment: I can send null though I could not understand how your question and all the rest  address the question why to bother substituting EventArgs for the generic type parameter at all. I did not ask about subverting the pattern of EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) to eliminate EventArgs parameter, only why to substitute EventArgs for generics (if event doesn't generate data)?

Comment: From the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` has a constraint of `where TEventArgs : EventArgs`.  This means that `EventArgs` is the most basic type, the most lightweight / efficient.  What else would you choose?